# show that max$\left\{n,m\right\} = n \cup m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

show that max$\left\{n,m\right\} = n \cup m\ $ Where $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers

Hey guys, I just got started on set theory and I'm kind of stuck with this question. Can anyone provide some insights on how to began this proof.

Also as a follow up (for curiosity sake), is the proof for minimum of $n, m$ exactly the same ?

Comment: Are these natural numbers? Ordinals? Subsets of a universal set ordered by inclusion?

Comment: They are probably ordinals, but it would be nice to see this stated explicitly. What do you already know about comparison between ordinals?

Comment: edited: Sorry for the missing part

Comment: What does $\cup$ between two natural numbers mean for you?

Comment: In set theory, isnt natural numbers sets ?

Comment: @some1fromhell: You can _represent_ natural numbers as set. Which representation do you use? Does recalling how the representation works help you see why the claim is true?

Comment: What is your definition of $\leq$ for natural numbers? I believe the standard definition (for Von Neumann ordinals) is $\subseteq$, which makes this question rather trivial.

Comment: I have proven in a previous part that $\leq$ iff $\subseteq$

Comment: Did you also prove that it provides a total ordering? In that case, $\max\{n,m\}$ is the $\subseteq$-largest of the two. Which answers the question, basically.

Comment: That I did not. So perhaps I can try using the trichotomy property to prove it ?

Comment: You have $n\subseteq m\vee m\subseteq n$ so that $n\cup m\in\{n,m\}$

Comment: @some1fromhell: In your context: $\min(\{m,n\}) = n \cap m$.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in the context of ordinals, it's easy for *any* ordinals:

The relation $\omega\in\omega'$ is a well-order between ordinals; furthermore $(\omega\in\omega)\implies (\omega\subset\omega')$. Hence, given $\omega$ and $\omega'$

- either $\omega\in\omega'$, so  $\omega\subset\omega'$, and $\omega\cup\omega'=\omega'=\max(\omega,\omega')$,
- or  $\omega=\omega'$, so trivially $\omega\cup\omega'=\omega=\max(\omega,\omega')$,
- or $\omega'\in\omega$: swap $\omega$ and $\omega'$ in the first case.

$$$$

Comment: Even I'm surprised, but using $\omega$ for arbitrary ordinals did actually trigger me...